# Nexus only downloading POMs from central repository rather than JARs

Tags: nexus

I am having a really strange problem with Nexus (version 2.6.2-01). I have tried enabling/disabling remote indexes but I am still running into the same problem. I have running the maven-release-plugin and whilst trying to download the dependencies of this plugin, it fails with the error

Could not find artifact org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:1.7.6 in nexus

I previously got the same error with org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.2 and I had to manually delete it using Browse Storage and then try to run the release plugin again to get it to download the artifact properly.

If I Browse Remote on the central repo in nexus, it shows the complete contents of the artifact, however if I Browse Index, the jar for groovy-all 1.7.6 is missing, this is the same if I do a general search for groovy-all 1.7.6.

My settings xml is configured as suggested in the Repository Management with Nexus book, i.e.

```
<mirror>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    <name>Nexus Public Repository Group</name>
    <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>

 <profile>
  <id>nexus</id>
  <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
  <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://central</url>
      <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
 <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://central</url>
      <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
</profile>

<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

This is getting really annoying as I expect Nexus to download require artifacts from central!

Thanks

Comment: The whole point of having an index is so that you don't have to mirror the entire contents of Maven Central. I would suggest you setup a schedule that periodically downloads and rebuilds your index. You must also explicitly enable the download of indexes on the proxy (by default it's disabled).

Comment: I am sorry to say but I have seen that advice everywhere. I was using a fresh installation of nexus and as mentioned in my original post I tried to enable indexes and have the most up to date indexes when seeing the problem above, so it really is not answering anything

Comment: Initially downloading a Maven Central takes a long time. Have you allowed sufficient time? Subsequent index updates are much faster because Lucene now support incremental index updates.

Answer (score 3):

Your local repository has probably cached the fact that the artifact was not found. Run a build of your project that requires groovy-all and force updates with

```
   mvn clean install -U
```

That should download the jar and pass.

Also index has nothing to do with what gets downloaded at all. It is just used for searches.

Comment: I have the same problem. But, forced clean install did not solve it.

Comment: Try deleting your local Maven repository and re-run with -U

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same/similar issue in Nexus 2.8.  Nexus would download the pom from central, but not the jar.  No amount of expiring/deleting the local Nexus cache would fix it.  I even upgraded to latest version 2.12.

To fix this, I increased the Request Timeout from 20 seconds to 60 seconds.
Log into Nexus as an Admin.  Click on "Server" in the menu on the left, and under "HTTP Request Settings" increase the Request Timeout to 60 (or higher).

Hopefully this helps someone down the road.